# Slow server response times from Django app on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, e-commerce

Ive grown quite stuck trying to figure out why my production Django application (E-commerce) has trouble with slow server response times on certain pages.

The pages affected has quite some database requests on it because of complicated relationships between Cars and Products i.e some chargers only work with some cars and some chargers span multiple categories etc etc.

The application is hosted on Heroku with a “Hobby Basic Postgres database” and "1 Professional Standard-1X dyno”.

For some reason the server takes between 7-10 seconds to respond to a request on the live server.
Locally everything works super smooth and fast with responses of maximum 0.5s on all pages.

Has anyone had this trouble before and has any idea of how to fix it?
Ive tried scaling the database and dynos without the response being any quicker..

I’ll attach som screenshots of logs and speed tests. And affected code Models, Views and Template.

Heroku Metrics: https://screenshot.net/z7r4jid 
 
Heroku Logs: https://screenshot.net/ndv7ot8 
Console Debugger: https://screenshot.net/m4310t3

Template: https://dpaste.de/tjEi 
View: https://dpaste.de/Bdut 
Models: https://dpaste.de/fNQY

The page is: https://www.evify.se

The pages with slow server response is all the car detail pages. 
Example: https://www.evify.se/laddboxar/jaguar-i-pace/

Would be extremely grateful if anyone has any idea, I’ve looked everywhere without finding any solutions :-/

Comment: how many db queries are performed by that `car_detail` view?

Comment: There are 5 separate queries and one merge query on those queries!

Comment: Have you already diagnosed your application with DjangoDebugToolbar or an APM solution?

Comment: can you confirm with [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) ? In your local enviroment try to diagnose the issue with django-debug-toolbar. You will get a better idea that why the page loading is slow.

Comment: @hendrikschneider & Nalin, Thank you guys i'll install it Immediately and try it out, will post a response soon!

Comment: @NalinDobhal & Hedrikschneider Hey guys, I implemented the django-debug-toolbar locally and here is a screenshot of the Car Detail page! I'm quite new to web development so i cant really tell what seems to be the problem. Can you see anything that seems to be out of order? Link= https://screenshot.net/nol8ya9